# How do I retrieve the data in the name list attribute (html) using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve the list of names from the inputs through jQuery.
Could anyone advise how I can do it?

The following inputs for example:

```
Henry | 25 | Financial Advisor
Eric  | 28 | Chemistry Professor
Lance | 30 | Database Administrator
```

How can I retrieve the names Henry, Eric, Lance using jQuery and the name[ ] attribute?

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="form_div">
 <form method="post" action="store_employee.php">
  <table id="employee_table" align=center>
   <tr id="row1">
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="age[]" placeholder="Enter Age"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="job[]" placeholder="Enter Job"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" onclick="add_row();" value="ADD ROW">
  <input type="submit" name="submit_row" value="SUBMIT">
 </form>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    function add_row()
{
    $rowno=jQuery("#employee_table tr").length;
    $rowno=$rowno+1;
    jQuery("#employee_table tr:last").after(
        "<tr id='row"+$rowno+"'>"+
            "<td><input type='text' name='name[]' placeholder='Enter Name'></td>"+
            "<td><input type='text' name='age[]' placeholder='Enter Age'></td>"+
            "<td><input type='text' name='job[]' placeholder='Enter Job'></td>"+
            "<td><input type='button' value='DELETE' onclick=delete_row('row"+$rowno+"')></td>"+
        "</tr>");
    }


function delete_row(rowno)
{
    jQuery('#'+rowno).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()`

```js
let res = $('tr').map((_, row) => {
  return [$(row).find('input').map((_, el) => el.value).get()]
}).get()

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="form_div">
    <form method="post" action="store_employee.php">
      <table id="employee_table" align=center>
        <tr id="row1">
          <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Name" value="Joe"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="age[]" placeholder="Enter Age" value="34"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="job[]" placeholder="Enter Job" value="President"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row1">
          <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Name" value="Bill"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="age[]" placeholder="Enter Age" value="77"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="job[]" placeholder="Enter Job" value="Flunky"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="button" onclick="add_row();" value="ADD ROW">
      <input type="submit" name="submit_row" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the name attribute to target the right inputs... Then look for the value.

```js
function add_row()
{
  $rowno=jQuery("#employee_table tr").length;
  $rowno=$rowno+1;
  jQuery("#employee_table tr:last").after(
    "<tr id='row"+$rowno+"'>"+
    "<td><input type='text' name='name[]' placeholder='Enter Name'></td>"+
    "<td><input type='text' name='age[]' placeholder='Enter Age'></td>"+
    "<td><input type='text' name='job[]' placeholder='Enter Job'></td>"+
    "<td><input type='button' value='DELETE' onclick=delete_row('row"+$rowno+"')></td>"+
    "</tr>");
}


function delete_row(rowno)
{
  jQuery('#'+rowno).remove();
}

$("#test").on("click",function(){
  
  var names =[];
  var nameInputs = $("input[name='name[]']");
  
  for (i=0;i<nameInputs.length;i++){
    names.push(nameInputs.eq(i).val());
  }
  console.log(names.join(","));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="form_div">
 <form method="post" action="store_employee.php">
  <table id="employee_table" align=center>
   <tr id="row1">
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="age[]" placeholder="Enter Age"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="job[]" placeholder="Enter Job"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" onclick="add_row();" value="ADD ROW">
  <input type="submit" name="submit_row" value="SUBMIT">
 </form>
</div>
<br>
<br>
  <button id="test">Show names in console</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = $("[name='name[]']");
```

Comment: This only seems to give the first name input.

Comment: should give you all names and you check them by:
`names[0] ( first name)
names[1] ( second name)
etc`